# No log folder is created under each task directory in cuckoo

Tags: sandbox, malware, sandbox-solution

I am running cuckoo 0.6 and everything is fine. My virtual machine is accessed by cuckoo and performs analysis. but after each analysis only tcpdupm.pcap  and report folder are created in the `/storage/analysis/taskiD/` directory and I can not see any behaviour analysis result in the html report generated at report folder.

It seems no dynamic analysis has been done and only static analysis result are shown! Every thing is enabled in configuration files.

I receive this error that shows there is no log folder:

> [modules.processing.behavior] ERROR: Analysis results folder does not exist at path "/home/sam/cuckoo/cuckoo/storage/analyses/7/logs"

Answer (score 0):

If you see only static analysis, then perhaps something went wrong with the execution of the binary. My best guest would be that the EXE (if it is), got corrupted.

Comment: Actually the main reason was inappropriate network setting between host and Virtual box analyser. The vm machine  could not return the result back to the host!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the main reason was inappropriate network setting between host and Virtual box analyser. The vm machine could not return the result back to the host!